# posting form by jquery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Basically i have submitted the form data by using jquery event in order to prevent page reload. Now , the informations of the form are not being displayed?

```js
$("#btn-ser1").click(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function() {
    alert("you are submitting" + $(this).serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form method="post" id="form">
    First Name :
    <input name="fname">Last Name :
    <input name="lname">Address :
    <input name="address">Contact No. :
    <input name="contact">Country:
    <input name="country">City:
    <input name="city">
  </form>
  <button type="button" id="btn-ser1">Serialize</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are just assigning a submit handler not triggering the event, your also not preventing page refresh

Comment: i have now added e.preventDefault(); ..How should i trigger the event... Right ! by clicking the button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't submitting, neither preventing the default action. You need:

```
$("#btn-ser1").click(function () {
  // remove this event handler                                                « #1
  // $("#form").submit(function (e) {
    // prevent refresh or default action                                      « #2
    e.preventDefault();
    // change $(this) to $("#form") as you are binding it to the button, not the form.
    alert("you are submitting" + $("#form").serialize());
    // submit to the server                                                   « #3
    $.post("path/to/post", $("#form").serialize());
  // });
});
```

You forgot to do the `#1`, `#2` and `#3` as mentioned.

Comment: Your code is adding an event handler for the "submit" event when the button is clicked. I don't think that's the intention.

Comment: @Pointy Kindly check?

Comment: Do i need to mention submit attribute type for the button?

Comment: @parthpahariya You don't need to!

Comment: @parthpahariya since you're doing all the work with JavaScript, the button type should be "button".

Comment: @PraveenKumar with comment submit form   .. $(this) will refer to the button not to the form .. and in the OP case  his button outside the form not inside

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef What the ... Sorry, updating.

Comment: Hey!.. I wish to store the form data in $_POST array ...How to do it?

Comment: @parthpahariya This is the answer. `POST` array has the form data. Just give the path to the PHP in `"path/to/post"`.

Comment: and even in the $.post statement , my path to post(url) is the same page itself

Comment: @parthpahariya What's your PHP location?

Comment: the same page i.e. localhost/test.html

Comment: @parthpahariya Use the same code, but instead just replace it as: `$.post("http://localhost/test.php", $("#form").serialize());`.

Comment: @parthpahariya `test.html` will not work man. PHP works only in `.php` files.

Comment: ok ! Thanxx.. Hey, just one more thing.. Does the above statement stores the serialised value of the form in $_POST array??

Comment: @parthpahariya Yes, it **will** store in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: @parthpahariya Sure. Anytime buddy! `:)`

Comment: Hey!the code is still totally non responsive.. nothing is happening

Comment: @parthpahariya Come to chat, let's sort it out. Click on the above link.

Answer (score -1):

Your button is the incorrect type. This only works with a "Submit" button. Use this HTML snippet instead:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn-ser1">Serialize</button>
```

Comment: This is not an issue. He's using jQuery.

Comment: the submit event of jquery does the same. So why to even select submit attribute type for the button

Comment: My apologies to the answer seekers.  I made the mistake of quickly scanning the OP's code snippet and responding without reading everything.  It is clearly obvious that the OP is trying to submit through the onclick handler and not the regular HTML form post so my answer is completely irrelevant.  I would remove my answer if I could.